# Use the streaming api to loop over fields instead of over objects

Tags: java, collections, java-stream

I want to use Java 8's stream api  for the following exercise:

- Given a `List<Person> persons`
- `Person` is a simple POJO with a name (string) and age (int) property
- Construct the following String `Names=[joe,diana,thomas]&Ages=[34,52,19]`

What I can easily do with streams is the following:

```
String result = persons.stream()
    .map(p -> "(" + p.getName() + "," + p.getAge() + ")")
    .collectors(Collectors.joining("&","persons=[","]");
```

Which will give `persons=[(joe,34)&(diana,52)&(thomas,19)]`, but I don't know how I can concatenate on the fields across mutiple person objects rather then on the properties of each person individually. It's like I need to flatmap the person to one property, and afterwards flatmap the list of persons a second time for the next property, and then combine these outputs. What would the syntax be for this?

The Person class is very simple. If possible, I would like a solution that is written in such a way that reflection is used to loop over ALL fields of a class instead of checking hardcoded only the "name" and "age" fields. Assume that all fields are simple properties like String or int (there are no nested classes or collections).

Comment: You'll probably need to write your own `Collector`. You also need to decide what result should be, if the objects of the stream are not all of the same type.

Comment: In the case of two fields (like name and age) you can write a simple solution using '''Collectors.toMap''' and '''Collectors.collectingandThen''', but it gets more complicated in the more generic case and you probably need to write your custom Collector as  @Andreas has said.

Comment: @alainlompo Map could only be used if you're absolute sure that names are unique. Since there is more that one [Zhang Wei](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-most-common-full-name-in-the-world) (or [James Smith](https://blogs.ancestry.com/cm/calling-james-smith-10-most-common-first-and-surname-combinations/)) in the world, you can't guarantee that, so Map is not a good choice.

Answer (score 4):

I guess having a class `Person` (as you describe), you would need a custom collector for this:

```
 String result = List.of(new Person(1, "david"), new Person(33, "eugene"))
            .stream()
            .parallel()
            .collect(Collector.of(
                    () -> new StringJoiner[]{new StringJoiner(",", "[", "]"), new StringJoiner(",", "[", "]")},
                    (sj, per) -> {
                        sj[0] = sj[0].add("" + per.getAge());
                        sj[1] = sj[1].add(per.getName());
                    },
                    (left, right) -> {
                        left[0] = left[0].merge(right[0]);
                        left[1] = left[1].merge(right[1]);
                        return left;
                    },

                    x -> "Names = " + x[1].toString() + "&Ages = " + x[0].toString()
            ));
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use

```
String result = persons.stream()
    .flatMap(p -> Stream.of(new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(true, p.getName()),
                            new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(false, ""+p.getAge())))
    .collect(Collectors.collectingAndThen(
        Collectors.partitioningBy(Map.Entry::getKey,
            Collectors.mapping(Map.Entry::getValue, Collectors.joining(",", "[", "]"))),
        m -> "Names="+m.get(true)+"&Ages="+m.get(false)));
```

`AbstractMap.SimpleEntry` is just a stand-in for the missing standard `Pair` type. If you have a `Pair` type in your project, you can use it instead; you just have to replace the `Map.Entry::getKey` and `Map.Entry::getValue` method references with the right ones to retrieve the first resp. second value of the pair.

The solution above is tailored to the case of two properties. An alternative which can be easily adapted to more than two properties would be

```
String result = persons.stream()
    .flatMap(p -> Stream.of(new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>("Names", p.getName()),
                            new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>("Ages", ""+p.getAge())))
    .collect(Collectors.collectingAndThen(
        Collectors.groupingBy(Map.Entry::getKey,
            Collectors.mapping(Map.Entry::getValue, Collectors.joining(",", "[", "]"))),
        m -> m.entrySet().stream()
              .map(e -> e.getKey()+"="+e.getValue()).collect(Collectors.joining("&"))));
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, this could be done with [`Collectors.teeing`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#teeing(java.util.stream.Collector,java.util.stream.Collector,java.util.function.BiFunction)), but it is available since Java 12:

```
String res =
    Stream.of(new Person(34, "joe"), new Person(52, "diana"), new Person(19, "thomas"))
        .collect(
            Collectors.teeing(
                Collectors.mapping(Person::getName, Collectors.joining(",")),
                Collectors.mapping(p -> "" + p.getAge(), Collectors.joining(",")),
                (names, ages) -> String.format("Names=[%s]&Ages=[%s]", names, ages)));

System.out.println(res); // Names=[joe,diana,thomas]&Ages=[34,52,19]
```

`Collectors.teeing` takes 3 arguments, in this code snipped specifically:

- Two Collector objects that are used to collect the names and ages of the people in the list.
- A BiFunction that is used to combine the results of the two collectors into a single string.